# FIX protocol using java

Tags: java, protocols, fix-protocol

I have developed a utility in Java using the [Financial Information eXchange(FIX)](http://fixprotocol.org/) protocol to pull data from an input stream. However, I currently have not found any test servers online to which I can connect to that implement the FIX protocol. Could someone please let me know how I can achieve this?

Comment: One question, why did you build your own engine when there are open source engines available ? Which you could have customized for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the comment DumbCoder. I have not built my own engine. Instead, I have built my utility on top of quickfixj. However, I want to connect to a test server from where I can pull streaming prices using the FIX protocol. Do you know if there are any test servers out there that will help me achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.quickfixj.org/ have an open source fix engine. It comes with an example that has a simple server. You might want to use their library for the client too rather than rebuilding a FIX engine from scratch...

Comment: Thanks for that assylias. I have already checked the example client/server app but what I'm looking for is to connect to a test server from where my program can pull streaming prices.

Comment: I am not aware of a free test server but most brokers would be able to provide you with a login to run some tests. So whoever you are trying to connect to should be able to help. Alternatively, you can amend the code of the server in quickfixj to return random prices...

Comment: Also not sure what you mean by streaming prices, do you mean an execution price? Or prices following an RFQ for example?

Comment: Thanks assylias. I mean an RFQ. So basically, I'll pass an initial message to the server with the product I want the streaming prices (quotes) for and then I'd be polling the server every 500ms or so for those prices. Does the example server in quickfixj push out streaming prices? I wasn't able to see it so far. Do I need to enable something to see that happen?

Comment: I don't think you can get streaming prices with the example as it is so you would need to modify it...

Answer (score 4):

You can use [CoralFIX](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/category/coralfix/) to quickly fire up a test server. It takes care of all the session level FIX messages, such as Logon, ResendRequest, SequenceReset, Heartbeat so you are ready to start exchanging messages with your client. Below a simple example:

```
import com.coralblocks.coralfix.FixMessage;
import com.coralblocks.coralreactor.client.Client;
import com.coralblocks.coralreactor.nio.NioReactor;
import com.coralblocks.coralreactor.util.Configuration;
import com.coralblocks.coralreactor.util.MapConfiguration;

public class SimpleFixApplicationServer extends FixApplicationServer {

    public SimpleFixApplicationServer(NioReactor nio, int port, Configuration config) {
        super(nio, port, config);
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleFixApplicationMessage(Client client, FixMessage fixMsg, boolean possDupe) {
        // do whatever you want to do with the application message received from this client...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NioReactor nio = NioReactor.create();

        MapConfiguration config = new MapConfiguration();

        // print all messages received and sent to STDOUT for debugging purposes
        // (default is false)
        config.add("debugMessages", "true");

        // accept as the client inbound sequence whatever 
        // sequence I receive in the first message coming from the client
        // (default is false)
        config.add("acceptInboundSeqFromClient", "false");

        Server server = new SimpleFixApplicationServer(nio, 45451, config);

        server.open();
        nio.start();
    }
}
```

A full explanation of the code above can be found [here](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/2014/07/fix-clients-and-servers-with-coralfix/).

**Disclaimer:** I am one of the developers of CoralFIX.

Comment: thanks for posting it. That looks like a really simple server. Is there a simple client example? I have a server sending out prices, I just want to connect to it and see the prices stream across.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you haven't built it in a vacuum, but rather to talk to some broker's FIX server? If that's the case, speak to your broker as they are likely to have a test server you could connect to.

Comment: Thanks for the comment aix. It's gonna be a while before I get the test server from my broker. Approximately 2 weeks. In the meantime, I'd like to know if there are any free test servers out there to which I can connect to that will help my program pull the streaming prices from the market.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want a hosted or a DIY solution. If you want to quickly bring up a FIX sessions without having to compile/build/setup then I would go for a hosted simulator.

We have an account with these guys http://www.fixsim.com/ and would recommend them (simple to setup and add more connections).

(I don't work for the company and get nothing to say this)

Answer (score -1):

you can try to search more information here: http://fixprotocol.org/discuss/

Answer (score -2):

I work for a broker, and you're more than welcome to connect to our Staging FIX servers. I do not know of any anonymous servers around, perhaps this is something the FIX community could set up..

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: Hi Chris.. Is this option still available?